# Intent with wrong filename in intent's data from downloaded files

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

I downloaded a file called test.npk via the android emulator's browser. It was saved in /sdcard/Download/test.npk:

```
$ adb -e shell ls /sdcard/Download/
test.npk
```

When I open the emulator's "Downloads" app and click on test.npk I get a Toast: "Can't open file"

When I look at the logcat I see that the intents it tries are wrong:

```
01-14 15:49:36.262    1232-1690/system_process I/ActivityManager﹕ START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/2 typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3} from uid 10005 on display 0
01-14 15:49:36.264    1337-1337/android.process.media W/DownloadManager﹕ Failed to start Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/2 typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3 }: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://downloads/all_downloads/2 typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3 }
```

As you can see the data of the intent is content://downloads/all_downloads/2. Why is that? How am I supposed to make an intent-filter for such an intent? I was expecting something like file://bla-bla/test.npk or at least something://bla/bal/test.npk

These are my intent filters:

```
    <activity android:name=".MyActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:exported="true"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.OtherActivity"
        android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"
        >
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
            android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
        <meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.OtherActivity" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="file" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.npk" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="http" />
            <data android:host="*" />
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.npk" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

SOLUTION:

Following @CommonsWare's suggestions, I am able to get to open my activity with the following intent-filter:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content"
                  android:host="*"
                  android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.fletech.npk"
                  android:pathPattern=".*"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

and to open the "file" I needed to use the following code:

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (null != action) {
        final Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (null != uri) {


            // this part is optional, if you want to get the filename to save it by the same name
            String filename = null;
            Long filesize = null;
            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[] {
                        OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, OpenableColumns.SIZE}, null, null, null );
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    filename = cursor.getString(0);
                    filesize = cursor.getLong(1);
                }
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null) {
                    cursor.close();
                }
            }



            // copy the "content://" into a cache / temporary / or permanent file
            final File file = new File(getCacheDir(), filename);
            InputStream is = null;
            OutputStream os = null;
            try {
                is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
                os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                try {
                    try {
                        final byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        int read;

                        while ((read = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            os.write(buffer, 0, read);
                        }

                        os.flush();
                    } finally {
                        os.close();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } finally {
                if (null != is) {
                    is.close();
                }
                if (null != os) {
                    os.close();
                }
            }

            // open the copied file
            if (file.exists()) {
                categoryPack = PackI18nCategory.fromFile(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> As you can see the data of the intent is content://downloads/all_downloads/2. Why is that?

Because that is what was handed to the Downloads app by the `ContentProvider` managing the downloads. It is a `Uri` to a stream handled by that downloads `ContentProvider`.

> How am I supposed to make an intent-filter for such an intent?

Support a scheme of `content` and a MIME type of `application/octet-stream`.

> I was expecting something like file://bla-bla/test.npk or at least something://bla/bal/test.npk

There is no requirement for a `ContentProvider` to use a file extension, and it is rather uncommon on the whole. Android in general does not do much with file extensions, preferring to use MIME types.

Comment: Application/octet-stream? Then almost every file will "open" my activity which is only able to handle my proprietary "npk" file format. Would it help if my web server would offer the file with different mime type? Can I just make my mime type? Let's say application/x-npk or is there a preferred way to call it?

Comment: @Gavriel: "Can I just make my mime type?" -- sure. Follow the vendor naming rules, and probably make something more elaborate than `application/x-npk` to reduce the odds of accidental collision. Then have your server serve your files with that MIME type.

Comment: yes, using my custom mime type starts my activity, but I am still not able to open the file. See my update at the bottom of the question

Comment: @Gavriel: Since your update does not state what your problem is, what errors you are getting, etc., I cannot really help you. You might wish to open up a fresh Stack Overflow question where you provide your current code and indicate specifically what problems you have. Note that you will want to have either the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your app, as some providers require that even for streams coming from the provider (for inexplicable reasons).

Comment: I wasn't able to open the file in my activity, but using the code I added at the end of my question (using several other stackowerflow answers) I could finally do it. The original question was about the intent-filter, so I accepted your answer